# UITableView with sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an app and in one view is a table. In the table I call the EventStore So It fills the table with your calendar events. I would like to have bars in the table like the ical app on the iphone so It breaks the days up with A bar the bar has the date (ex. March 25, 2011). Below is the code for the table

//eventsTable.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@interface eventsTable : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

IBOutlet UITableView *Table;
EKEventStore *eventStore;
EKEvent *event;

EKEventViewController *detailViewController;

EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
NSMutableArray *eventsList;
}
-(IBAction) done;
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday;
@property (nonatomic, retain) 
IBOutlet UITableView *Table;

@property (nonatomic, retain) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (nonatomic, retain) EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventsList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) EKEventViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

//eventsTable.m

```
#import "eventsTable.h"

@implementation eventsTable
@synthesize eventsList, eventStore, defaultCalendar, detailViewController,Table;
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Events List";

// Initialize an event store object with the init method. Initilize the array for events.
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

self.eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0];

// Get the default calendar from store.
self.defaultCalendar = [self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

//  Create an Add button 




// Fetch today's event on selected calendar and put them into the eventsList array
[self.eventsList addObjectsFromArray:[self fetchEventsForToday]];

[Table reloadData];

}
-(IBAction) done{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Fetching events happening in the next 24 hours with a predicate, limiting to the default calendar 
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday {

    NSDate *startDate1 = [NSDate date];

    // endDate is 1 day = 60*60*24 seconds = 86400 seconds from startDate
    NSDate *endDate1 = [NSDate distantFuture];

    // Create the predicate. Pass it the default calendar.
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
    //NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate 
//                                               calendars:calendarArray]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate1 endDate:endDate1 calendars:calendarArray];

// Fetch all events that match the predicate.
NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];





events = 
[events sortedArrayUsingSelector:
 @selector(compareStartDateWithEvent:)];

self.eventsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:events];
[Table reloadData];

 return events;
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   {
return eventsList.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *result = nil;

if ([tableView isEqual:self.Table] == YES){

    static NSString *EventsCellIdentifier = @"Events";

    /* We have the index path so let's get the corresponding
     event from the array of events */
    EKEvent *event1 = [self.eventsList 
                       objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    /* Try to get a reusable table cell */
    result = 
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EventsCellIdentifier];

    if (result == nil){
        result = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                   reuseIdentifier:EventsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    /* The title text of the cell will be the title of the event */
    result.textLabel.text = event1.title;
    result.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    result.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];


    /* Now let's format the date and the time of the event
     and display it as the subtitle of the cell */
    NSCalendar *calendar =  [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = 
    [calendar components:
     NSYearCalendarUnit | 
     NSMonthCalendarUnit | 
     NSDayCalendarUnit |
     NSHourCalendarUnit |
     NSMinuteCalendarUnit |
     NSSecondCalendarUnit
                fromDate:event1.startDate];

    NSDateComponents *components1 = 
    [calendar components:
     NSYearCalendarUnit | 
     NSMonthCalendarUnit | 
     NSDayCalendarUnit |
     NSHourCalendarUnit |
     NSMinuteCalendarUnit |
     NSSecondCalendarUnit
                fromDate:event1.endDate];

    if ([components hour] == 0 &&
        [components minute] == 0 &&
        [components second] == 0){


        NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents: components1];
        NSString *string = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date dateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

        NSDate *date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents: components];
        NSString *string1 = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date1 dateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

        result.detailTextLabel.text = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"All Day from %@ - %@",string1,string,
         (long)[components month],
         (long)[components day],
         (long)[components year],
         (long)[components1 month],
         (long)[components1 day],
         (long)[components1 year]];

    } else {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents: components1];
        NSString *string = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date dateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        NSDate *date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents: components];
        NSString *string1 = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date1 dateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        result.detailTextLabel.text = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",string1,string,

         (long)[components month],
         (long)[components day],
         (long)[components year],
         (long)[components hour],
         (long)[components minute],
         (long)[components1 hour],
         (long)[components1 minute]];


    }

}

return(result);
[event release];
[eventsList release];
[eventStore release];
[result release];


}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.eventsList = nil;
self.view = nil;
    self.Table = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [Table release];
    [eventStore release];
[eventsList release];
[defaultCalendar release];
[detailViewController release];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to split each day up into a separate section and implement the proper UITableViewDataSource protocols for section indexes: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Here is a tutorial: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/

Comment: I keep trying and am having no luck. I don't understand hod to get this working with changing variables. I posted my code above can you show me how I implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change the section titles with the date you want to display. You do this by implementing the **(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section** method.

Comment: But how do I use if(section == 0)
return @"Countries to visit";
else
return @"Countries visited";
} if its ever changing because It has to do with the other arrays that update.

Comment: well my guess is you'll have to come up with a way of identifying the events in a given day and create an array of the dates that have  events.  Then when you are populating the table with the events, you break the events into sections by dates and label the sections with the corresponding date from your date array.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code despite the question. You must release the resources before the return.

```
return(result);
[event release];
[eventsList release];
[eventStore release];
[result release];
```

Comment: I don't see a add comment link.